# vue.js pass Object to component

Tags: vuejs2

I have 2 vue components, I would like to pass an object from the parent to the child component.

componentA

```
<template lang="pug">
  .wrapper
    treenode(:model=treeData)
    div -----------------
    div {{treeData}}

</template>

<script>
  import treenode from './treenode.vue'

  export default {
    props : ['items']
  , components : { treenode : treenode }
  , created(){
        this.treeData = {name:"test"}
    }
</script>
```

comp treenode

```
 export default {
    props : {
      model: {
        type : Object
      , default : function(){ return { name : "default" } }
      }
    }
```

model in comp treenode is always the default value

Comment: `<child-component parentProp="prop" />` so the name of the prop inside the child component will be "parentProp" and contain parent viewmodels "prop" data property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing the prop value in the child component tag correctly.

You need to wrap `treeData` in quotes:

```
treenode(:model='treeData')
```

Comment: I hate replacement syntax like pug, coffeescript, etc... and even more so when it's indentation-based.